# Existence of infinite unique FSAs

Tags: finite-automata, theory

It is reasonably simple to show that there are an infinite number of different finite state automata that can be constructed, but has it been proven if there is an infinite number of unique finite state automata? Meaning no automata that recognize the same language.

I asked my professor and he didn't know, and I haven't been able to find anything about it online.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure. You can easily find an automaton that recognizes the language $\{a\}$, and one that recognizes the language $\{aa\}$, and one that recognizes the language $\{aaa\}$.  You can probably see where I'm going from here...

Answer (score 0):

There is no language $L$ that has a 'unique' automaton. For this language $L$ there is however a unique *minimal* automaton, this is a consequence of the [Myhill-Nerode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myhill%E2%80%93Nerode_theorem) theorem.

From the minimal automaton for $L$ we can construct an infinite amount of different non-minimal automaton for the same language $L$ by simply adding states. If adding unreachable states does not convince you, we could also add states that share the same equivalence class in the same [Myhill-Nerode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myhill%E2%80%93Nerode_theorem) relation.

Comment: The OP asked the opposite question: are there infinitely many regular languages?

Comment: I was not sure. The combination of "Meaning no automata that recognize the same language." and the first observation in the question made me interpret the question this way.